# exception when trying to update records in the database

Tags: android, sql-server, exception, android-edittext, sql-update

what i am trying to do is updating the records where it will search for the itemnumber and use is id to change the shelfnumber in another table based on what is in the edittext

this is the error i get when i tries to update the record

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.

and that happends at my public class and on my `preparedStatement.executeUpdate();`

```
public class UpdatePro extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;
    String item = cardnumberbox.getText().toString();
    String shelf = shelfnumberbox.getText().toString();      

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (item.trim().equals("") || shelf.trim().equals(""))
            z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = getString(R.string.Forbindelses_fejl);;
                } else {
                    String text1 = item;
                    {
                        if(text1.substring(0,1).startsWith("K"))
                        {
                            text1 =  text1.substring(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            text1=  text1 ;//.substring(0));
                        }
                    }
                    String text2 = shelf;
                    {
                        if(text2.substring(0,1).startsWith("R"))
                        {
                            text2 =  text2.substring(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            text2=  text2 ;//.substring(0));
                        }
                    }
                    String query = "Update PS set ShelfNumber = "+text2+ " from file.ItemPart PS "+ " join file.item P on P.id = PS.id "+ " where P.ItemNumber = '"+text1 + "'";
                   PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                    z = getString(R.string.Update_succes);

                    isSuccess = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", ex);
                z = getString(R.string.Exceptions);
            }
        }
        return z;
```

Comment: if i do that then is not a statement

Comment: I think that `"Update PS set ShelfNumber = "+text2+ "` **should be** `"Update PS set ShelfNumber =' "+text2+ " '`

Comment: i still running in to the exception

Comment: `shelfnumber` is nvarchar(100) `itemnumber` is varchar(20)

Comment: `File` is a reserved word try ;`[file.ItemPart]`

Comment: how typical it always thoose small things that screws up everything:P after i did`[file].[ItemPart]` `[file].[Item]` then it worked thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try :**

```
public class UpdatePro extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
String z = "";
Boolean isSuccess = false;
String item = cardnumberbox.getText().toString();
String shelf = shelfnumberbox.getText().toString();      

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    if (item.trim().equals("") || shelf.trim().equals(""))
        z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
    else {
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = getString(R.string.Forbindelses_fejl);;
            } else {
                String text1 = item;
                {
                    if(text1.substring(0,1).startsWith("K"))
                    {
                        text1 =  text1.substring(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text1=  text1 ;//.substring(0));
                    }
                }
                String text2 = shelf;
                {
                    if(text2.substring(0,1).startsWith("R"))
                    {
                        text2 =  text2.substring(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text2=  text2 ;//.substring(0));
                    }
                }
                String query = "Update PS set ShelfNumber = "+text2+ " from [file].[ItemPart] PS "+ " join [file].[item] P on P.id = PS.id "+ " where P.ItemNumber = '"+text1 + "'";
               PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                z = getString(R.string.Update_succes);

                isSuccess = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", ex);
            z = getString(R.string.Exceptions);
        }
    }
    return z;
```

Comment: Good Luck @Kewin Björk Nielsen